# Проблема с рекурсивным методом

Tags: java, рекурсия

Суть задачи состоит в том чтобы убрать из массива строк соседние элементы указывающие в противоположных направлениях (South-North, East-West), и это исключение должно повторяться пока не останется таких пар. 
 Проблема в том что программа при вводных данных ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"], должна вывести ["WEST"], но в последнем шаге после проверки if что-то происходит и к уже готовому массиву добавляется 2 пустых значения в начале и вывод становится ["","","WEST"]. Хотя в отладчике до последнего момента все как надо. Почему так происходит?

```
public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Task task = new Task();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(task.dirReduc(new String[]{"NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"})));
   }
}


class Task {
public static String[] dirReduc(String[] arr) {
    char c,b;
    int count = 0;
   /*Цикл проверяет на наличие двух "противоположных" соседей и
   меняет строки на пустые в случае такого совпадения.*/
    for(int i = 0; i<arr.length-1;i++){
        c = arr[i].charAt(0);
        b = arr[i+1].charAt(0);
        if((c=='S'&&b=='N')||(c=='N'&&b=='S')) {arr[i] = ""; arr[i+1] = ""; i = i+2; count++;}
        else if((c=='W'&&b=='E')||(c=='E'&&b=='W')) {arr[i] = ""; arr[i+1] = ""; i = i+2; count++;}
    }

   /*Создается List в который происходит копирование всех не пустых строк и из него
копируется в новый массив который либо возвращается как ответ либо происходит рекурсивный вызов самого метода.*/
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String y: arr) {if(y.length()>1) list.add(y);}
    String[] arr2 = list.toArray(new String[0]);

   //Если произошло изменение и длина больше 1 то повторить.
    if(count>0&&arr2.length>1){dirReduc(arr2);}

    return arr2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if (count > 0 && arr2.length > 1) {return dirReduc(arr2);}
```

Нужно добавить return

И  `i = i+2;`, `for` тоже инкрементирует, в итоге +3 получается

Comment: благодарю все работает. Подскажите пожалуйста почему в этом моменте так важен return?

Comment: @АлександрКочуров Вот это да! Я уже почти час бьюсь как бабочка об стекло и как рыба об лед, а Вам теперь понадобились дополнительные объяснения? Ну, давайте посмотрим, может быть у katso получится лучше.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(count>0&&arr2.length>1){dirReduc(arr2);}
```

Не мешало бы использовать значение, возвращаемое `dirReduc`:

```
if (count > 0 && arr2.length > 1)
{
  arr2 = dirReduc(arr2);
}
```

Comment: dirReduc возвращает массив строк, arr2 - массив строк. Я вас не понял.

Comment: @АлександрКочуров `dirReduc` возвращает не тот массив, который туда передается.

Comment: Я еще больше вас не понял, в этом суть метода, конечно он должен вернуть не тот массив который в него передается.

Comment: конечно, теста ради я вызываю его из главного класса, передавая ему параметром выше обозначенный массив и вывожу в консоль через Arrays.toString. Последний вопрос не совсем понял. Я изменяю массив с помощью dirReduc, переношу нужную мне информацию в новый массив и повторно передаю его dirReduc если это требуется.

Comment: @АлександрКочуров Покажите, пожалуйста, как Вы вызываете `dirReduc` первый раз, - добавьте код в вопрос.